# What tool is needed to remove a Shimano HG-50 freewheel?

Tags: maintenance, shimano, hub, freewheel

What tool is needed to remove a Shimano HG-50 freewheel from the wheel hub? It looks like a 12mm or 13mm Allen key. Will this do it or is there some detail I have missed?

Comment: See http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Is that different from the link in my answer below?

Comment: It is, I believe, the same link.  I looked it up and posted my message before I noticed you'd linked to it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've not found a good graphic of the part yet. The bolt in question was inside the hub of the wheel and a 12mm Allen Key did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT:

This is an HG 50 Cassette.
[image: HG-50 Cassette]

[image: Exploded view of Shimano freehub]

This is an exploded view of a Shimano freehub showing the 10mm or 12mm allen key used to remove the freehub from the hub shell. I believe this is the allen you are referencing, but it need not be removed to remove the gear cluster.

Instructions for removing either a cassette or a freewheel can be found [here](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal-and-installation).

If it is truly a freewheel. then this is the appropriate tool, the Park FR-1:

[image: The Park Tool FR-1]

If you need a cassette remover, then this is the appropriate tool, the Park FR-5:

[image: Park Tool FR-5]

along with this one, or a similar chain whip:

[image: Park Tool Chain Whip]

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. None of these look correct. The nut is within the hub of the wheel, it doesn't seem to come out. It has a thread on the outside which screws into the inner of the cassette hub. I'm not with the bike right now but I will update the question later with a photograph.

Comment: There is a 10mm or 12mm Allen key used to remove the freehub from the hub shell of the wheel. It has nothing to do with removing either the cassette or freewheel gear cluster. I've pictured the HG-50 Cassette above, to show where the FR-5 cassette tool or FR-1 freewheel tool would fit.

Answer (score 1):

The HG-50 is a *cassette*, not a *freewheel*. The freewheel is a part of the hub, and normally you never have to remove it. (On old bikes, the cassette and the freewheel came as one unit, and screwed onto the hub body. Nobody makes them like that anymore.)

Read the Park Tools link that Daniel gave you. Go about halfway down to "Cassette Cog Lockring Removal and Installation" - it should tell you everything. You'll need a lockring tool to unscrew the lockring, a wrench to hold the lockring tool, and a chainwhip to hold the cogs and keep them from spinning as you're loosening the lockring.

Comment: Daniel reposted the link in my answer, as a comment.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the misattribution. Please don't hit me.

Comment: I think you're probably too far away to hit.  And I don't have any ICBMs. I think you're safe, this time. But don't let it happen again.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a sprocket chain whip for holding it and a tool for opening the sprocket lock ring...it's very easy job with the proper tool...