# What cassette remover tool I should order for Shimano CS-HG50?

Tags: cassette

There is duplicate question
[What tool is needed to remove a Shimano HG-50 freewheel?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8224/what-tool-is-needed-to-remove-a-shimano-hg-50-freewheel?newreg=90fb821fdd144a84b2b2eedbc5b27658)

but I need a non-park tool tool. Something I can order from AliExpress.

The cassete looks like this[image]

I don't have enough reputation on bicycles to add comment to the duplicate question  (so my only option is to post it as question)

Comment: If you want us to give you a link to an Alibaba item then this is a shopping question. This is best asked in [chat].

Comment: All the current Shimano cassettes use the same splining on the tool (e.g. Park Tool FR-5; Note that there are variants like FR-5.2 GT which require specific axle formats (Thru Axle in the GT case), but the splining is the same ). So, just search for shimano cassette tool, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Shimano cassettes, and all SRAM cassettes other than "XD" ones, have the same spline pattern.  If you search for "cassette lockring tool" you will find lots of compatible tools.  Virtually the only incompatible ones will be SRAM XD and Campagnolo, and they will be specifically labeled as such.